# ActiveRecord -- user has_many events and belongs to those events as member

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I want to set up a relationship where users can start events and then also join them as members. I figured this uses a many to many relationship, but it also has a simple belongs_to relationship from Event to User.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_secure_password
  has_many :events # => Owning
  has_many :events, through: :members  # => Joining
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user # => event owner
  has_many :users, through: :members # => joining users
end

class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :event
end
```

But I'm having trouble getting queries like `Event.first.members` to work... I can't figure out what's preventing me from using these methods. Am I thinking of these relationships the wrong way? My Schema.rb:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20161205220807) do

  create_table "events", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.string   "location"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  add_index "events", ["user_id"], name: "index_events_on_user_id"

  create_table "members", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "event_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  add_index "members", ["event_id"], name: "index_members_on_event_id"
  add_index "members", ["user_id"], name: "index_members_on_user_id"

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "email"
    t.integer  "age"
    t.string   "password_digest"
    t.datetime "created_at",      null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",      null: false
  end

end
```

Comment: are you getting an error? if so can you show the actual error you're getting?

Comment: `NoMethodError: undefined method 'members' for #<Event:0x007faa0e39b0d8>`

Comment: Looks like your has many through are backwards.  `belongs_to :user # => event owner
has_many :users  has_many :members, through: :users`.  Same with events in your user model. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association

Comment: Okay yeah I thought that might be the problem. In that case though I get this error: `ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughAssociationNotFoundError: Could not find the association :users in model Event` (edit: I needed to add has_many :users to the Event model)

Comment: Have to add that.  I have it in the comment (formatting in my comment sucks though). `has_many :users`

Comment: Adding has_many :users to Event gives me a stack level too deep error: `SystemStackError: stack level too deep`

Comment: Did you fix events too? I would also break it down a bit and get rid of the belongs_to :user until you get the has_many relations fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated** to fix my mistake

```
  class User < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_secure_password
      has_many :members
      has_many :events, through: :members
    end

    class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
      #belongs_to :user # => event owner
      has_many :members
      has_many :users, through: :members

    class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :user
      belongs_to :event
    end
```

If this is giving you a stack level too deep error im guessing the issue is elsewhere.  Your logs might have more info.

Comment: Appreciate the help, but this gives me the stack level too deep error... I'll have to look more into how these relationships work under the hood but am pretty frustrated. Perhaps I am missing a polymorphism step here?